# lapply() to spark.lapply() conversion issue

Tags: r, lapply, sparkr

I am having an issue while converting lapply() method in R to spark.lapply(). So my R code looks like this

```
> lst <- lapply(1:(length(SampleData$A)-n), function(i) SampleData$A[i:(i+n)])
> names(lst) <- paste0("SampleData$A", seq_along(lst))
> list2env(lst, envir = .GlobalEnv)
```

I am integrating the same in sparkR using spark.lapply()

```
count <- function(i) {
    df2$A[i:(i+n)]
}
lst <- spark.lapply(1:(length(df2$A)-n), count)
```

However, I am getting the following error:

```
Error in writeType(con, serdeType) :
  Unsupported type for serialization nonstandardGenericFunction
```

I am relatively new to sparkR, so any help would be appreciated. Thank you !

Comment: can you post sample data?

Comment: @ManikantaMaheshByra
> lst$SampleData$A1 <- [1] 86.83  1.94 14.58 38.88 95.98
> lst$SampleData$A2 <- [1] 1.94 14.58 38.88 95.98 49.66
> lst$SampleData$A3 <- [1] 14.58 38.88 95.98 49.66 75.33

Answer (score 0):

In my (limited) experience with `spark.lapply` basically what you need to do is make sure you are explicit with your namespace; **especially** if you are using external packages.

In other words you should try to be explicit what any other kind of variables that `spark.lapply` needs to be aware of that needs to go in the function inside. Although the help file says that it generally picks things up from the global environment, this approach allows you to keep your sanity when it doesn't work...

In pseudo-code your lapply should really look like this

```
spark.lapply([(x1, y1), (x2, y2), (x3, y3)], function(x) do_stuff(x[1], x[2]))
```

where `do_stuff` should not rely on anything beyond its own environment. In my experience any kind of options such as `option(na.pass)` needs to be defined within the function as well. The manual also tells you to re-specify any libraries you might have loaded as well!

With respect to your code, I would alter it to look like this:

```
count <- function(i, df2) {
  df2$Sepal.Length[i:(i+n)]
}

df2 <- iris
n = 3

# creating a new list of parameters as in the code example above
# this will be:
# [(integer, dataframe)]
input_list <- lapply(1:(length(df2$Sepal.Length)-n), function(x) return(list(i=x, df2=df2)))

# doing what you did above
lst <- lapply(input_list, function(x) count(x$i, x$df2))
splst <- spark.lapply(input_list, function(x) count(x$i, x$df2))
```

If you want to use your environment variables I would recommend setting up the `lapply` like this:

```
lst <- lapply(1:(length(df2$Sepal.Length)-n), function(x) count(x$i, df2))
splst <- spark.lapply(1:(length(df2$Sepal.Length)-n), function(x) count(x$i, df2))
```

It normally works, but sometimes weird things happen if they are objects which are not your standard R types (e.g. `xgb.Dmatrix` objects)